# Android runtime condition to check whether the dependency is available or not

Tags: android, dependencies, dex

I am using "provided" dependency configuration in my library project.  I want to include a runtime condition to check whether the dependency is available or not so that I can change the behavior of the library and make sure that it keeps working.

Any idea on how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What dpeendency injection system are you using?  Dagger?  Butterknife?  Something else?  DI isn't built into android.

Comment: I haven't tried this with `provided` yet, but with `<uses-library>` and `android:required="false"`, the typical recipe is to use `Class.forName()` to look up a class from the library. If it succeeds, you have the library. If it throws an exception (`NameNotFoundException`, IIRC), you do not have the library.

Comment: Thank you! That was helpful.